# Woocommerce shop page does not display header and footer

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having an issue with woocommerce so I'm making this themes everything well well expect the shop page which does not display header and footer area all other pages do.Does anyone know what is the problem

Comment: do you have any code snippets

Comment: Is there code that's the issue? Can you try using a default theme such as Twenty Fifteen and see if that works? It's likely that you're not properly calling the header and footer areas in WordPress.

Comment: they all show on other page and the code for shop page is default code.or do i need to add something piece of code on shop pages in order to show header and footer

Comment: Please confirm that it works with a default theme. Woocommerce templates look for ´header-shop.php´ which falls back to ´header.php´

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code is available or not

```
get_header( 'shop' ); archive-product.php
```

in your theme woocommerce folder or plugin woocommerce folder.

Comment: Not working for me :(